# after karaf login showing some Unsatisfied Requirements:

Tags: osgi, karaf, opendaylight

i was installed one feature called odl-mdsal-apidocs, at the time of installation it throws the following  exception.

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-mdsal-apidocs
Unsatisfied Requirements:
Error executing command: Error restarting bundles:
    Could not resolve module: org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [280]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. 
Unable to resolve resource org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.annotation' from resources javax.annotation-api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.annotation-api"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0"] and org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.3.v20170209-1843"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; singleton:="true"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation)
 |
export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.annotation
  javax.annotation-api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.annotation-api"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0"]

Chain 2:
  org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"]
import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(&(version>=23.3.0)(!(version>=24.0.0))))
 |
export: osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base; uses:=javax.annotation
  com.google.guava [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.google.guava"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="23.3.0.jre"]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation)
 |
export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.annotation
  org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.3.v20170209-1843"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; singleton:="true"]
opendaylight-user@root>osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.rest.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.api)"
Unsatisfied Requirements:
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="
(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.rest.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="
(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.api)"
```

when i'm trying to restart the karaf, it's displaying some  Unsatisfied Requirements as follows :

```
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="
(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.rest.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="
(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.api)"
```

how can i resolve this issue,please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

you are likely hitting [this bug](https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/NETCONF-516) which will be fixed in the upcoming
Oxygen release.

Comment: yeah, you can grab carbon from the odl downloads page. oxygen should be released in the next week or so as well.